# Restart process using monit, when the checksum of a file changed

Tags: monit

I want to restart a process monitored by monit, when the checksum of a file failed. Currently i use

```
check process prosody with pidfile /var/run/prosody/prosody.pid
    depends certificate_file
    start program "/etc/init.d/prosody start"
    stop program "/etc/init.d/prosody stop"
    restart program "/etc/init.d/prosody restart"

check file certificate_file with path /etc/prosody/certs/fullchain.pem
    if changed checksum then exec "/usr/bin/monit restart prosody"
```

But i would like to have some command like `if changed checksum then restart prosody` instead of using the monit binary via `exec`.

The `restart` action seems to be limited to restart the currently monitored process, so an action in a `check file` block doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put action **restart**

```
check process prosody with pidfile /var/run/prosody/prosody.pid
    depends certificate_file
    start program "/etc/init.d/prosody start"
    stop program "/etc/init.d/prosody stop"
    restart program "/etc/init.d/prosody restart"

check file certificate_file with path /etc/prosody/certs/fullchain.pem
    if changed checksum then restart
```

Event restart will be propagated to all dependency with log similar to

```
[CEST Mar 27 11:57:30] error    : 'certificate_file' checksum was changed for /etc/prosody/certs/fullchain.pem
[CEST Mar 27 11:57:30] info     : 'certificate_file' trying to restart
[CEST Mar 27 11:57:30] info     : 'prosody ' stop: /etc/init.d/prosody stop
[CEST Mar 27 11:57:30] info     : 'prosody ' start: /etc/init.d/prosody start
```

Be aware that Monit will continue to trigger event again and again with this configuration -> so trigger restart continuously.

Also it seems, *start* and *stop* action **must** to be specified else nothing is done (could be a bug). (Tested with monit 5.14)

---

EDIT : With an upgraded Monit version 5.21.0, the behavior is way better and there is not endless restart loop

```
[CEST Mar 27 13:47:22] info     : 'certificate_file' trying to restart
[CEST Mar 27 13:47:22] info     : 'prosody' stop: '/etc/init.d/prosody stop'
[CEST Mar 27 13:47:22] info     : 'certificate_file' checksum has not changed
[CEST Mar 27 13:47:22] info     : 'prosody' start: '/etc/init.d/prosody start'
```

Comment: Nice, i did not know that restarts are propagated this way.